# RMagick unable to open image in the documentation demo

Tags: ruby, imagemagick, rmagick

I could not get RMagick to open any file (I started with a pdf, but moved to png, thinking the problem lied with the pdf). I just tried the *RMagick equivalent of "Hello, world"*

```
require 'RMagick'
include Magick
cat = ImageList.new("Cheetah.jpg")
cat.display
```

and I continue to get 'unable to open image' 'no such file or directory'errors. I double checked to make sure the Cheetah.png file was in the correct spot (ex/images subdirectory where I installed the RMagick documentation) and it is.

```
Magick::ImageMagickError: unable to open image `Cheetah.jpg': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2701
from /Users/alexpetersen/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rmagick-2.16.0/lib/rmagick_internal.rb:1616:in `read'
from /Users/alexpetersen/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rmagick-2.16.0/lib/rmagick_internal.rb:1616:in `block in initialize'
from /Users/alexpetersen/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rmagick-2.16.0/lib/rmagick_internal.rb:1615:in `each'
from /Users/alexpetersen/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rmagick-2.16.0/lib/rmagick_internal.rb:1615:in `initialize'
from (irb):11:in `new'
from (irb):11
from /Users/alexpetersen/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
from /Users/alexpetersen/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
from /Users/alexpetersen/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
from /Users/alexpetersen/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
from /Users/alexpetersen/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/alexpetersen/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
from /Users/alexpetersen/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
from /Users/alexpetersen/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
from /Users/alexpetersen/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
from /Users/alexpetersen/Desktop/FormFinder/FormFinderApp/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/alexpetersen/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
from /Users/alexpetersen/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
from /Users/alexpetersen/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
from /Users/alexpetersen/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
from /Users/alexpetersen/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /Users/alexpetersen/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Does the image really exist?

Comment: Use the full path to the image and see if that works. Nominally the image should be in the directory from which you issue the command (your working directory) if you do not want to provide the full path

Comment: @aristotll the image does really exist, and is in the directory it should be.